# How to generate Excel epplus C# new sheet with different content in each sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, web, epplus

I want to generate excel with Epplus C# on my WEB.
I want to create multi sheets in Excel with different content on each sheet.
I think maybe I have to use loop For.
but I do not know how to coding.
Please help me. Sorry for my bad english.

```
    using (ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            var fullFilename = "warming up specification.xlsx";
            var oldFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/File" + "/" + fullFilename);

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(oldFilePath, FileMode.Open))
            {


                pkg.Load(stream);
                ExcelWorksheet ws = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets[1];


                //set Fixed Cell value
                foreach (var item in dict)
                {
                    ws.Cells[item.Key].Value = item.Value; 
                }
                ws.Cells.Style.Font.Size = 13;
                ws.Cells.Style.WrapText = true;
                ws.PrinterSettings.PaperSize = ePaperSize.A4;

                ws.PrinterSettings.FitToPage = true;
                ws.PrinterSettings.FooterMargin = 0M;
                ws.PrinterSettings.TopMargin = 0M;
                ws.PrinterSettings.LeftMargin = 0M;
                ws.PrinterSettings.RightMargin = 0M;

                ws.Cells["A1:AC1"].Merge = true;
                ws.Cells["A1:AC1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                ws.Cells["A1:AC1"].Style.Font.Size = 25;
                ws.Cells["A1:AC1"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                ws.Cells["A1:AC1"].Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;
                ws.Cells["A1:AC1"].Value = "TEST";
                // ws.Cells["F1:L1"].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ws.Cells["F1:L1"].Style.Border.Left.Style = ws.Cells["F1:L1"].Style.Border.Right.Style = ws.Cells["F1:L1"].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;

                Random rand = new Random();
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "_" + rand.Next(1, 999) + "_" + fullFilename);
                Response.BinaryWrite(pkg.GetAsByteArray());
                Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: this link help you to create simple excel file in your project :
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/export-to-excel-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Do you need to export multiple files or multiple worksheets in same file?

Comment: multiple worksheets in same file Sry my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are looking for is multiple worksheets in same file then just add another worksheet.

```
ExcelWorksheet ws1 = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("WorkSheet1");
//your operations for worksheet1

ExcelWorksheet ws2 = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("WorkSheet2");
//your operations for worksheet2
```

Comment: It works for me but I have my old file 
The result 3 sheets
Sheet1 ,Worksheet1,Worksheet2 
I want Worksheet1 is the first sheet of excel
what should I do?

Comment: Just add another worksheet and order it however you want

Comment: Well, then could you, maybe, accept and upvote my answer?

Comment: I cannot because my reputation is less than 15.